# Terraform/Google External Table for Partition Parquet Files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform

I'm trying to create a terraform resource for an external partitioned parquet file but I keep getting a `Error: googleapi: Error 400: Field, CREATED_TIMESTAMP, is present in both Table Schema and Hive-Partition key., invalid` error. For some reason, when I run this in the BQ console it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `project.poc.parquet_test`
WITH PARTITION COLUMNS (
  CREATED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
  DE_TYPE STRING
)
OPTIONS (
uris = ['gs://poc_bucket/invalid_records/*.parquet'],
format = 'PARQUET',
hive_partition_uri_prefix = 'gs://poc_bucket/invalid_records/',
require_hive_partition_filter = false);
```

This is how it's defined in terraform file:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "invalid_table" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.cmu_dataset.dataset_id
  table_id = "invalid_store_item"

  labels = local.labels
  deletion_protection = false

  external_data_configuration {
    autodetect = false
    source_format = "PARQUET"

    source_uris = [
      "gs://poc_bucket/invalid_records/*.parquet",
    ]

    hive_partitioning_options {
      mode = "CUSTOM"
      source_uri_prefix = "gs://poc_bucket/invalid_records/{CREATED_TIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP}/{DE_TYPE:STRING}"
    }

    schema = file("bq_schemas/invalid_records_table_schema.json")
  }
}
```

The supporting BigQuery schema is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "TRANSACTION_ID",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "PLAN",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "ERROR_REASON",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "CREATED_TIMESTAMP",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
  },
  {
    "name": "DEPT_TYPE",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

I got this format from [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6788#issuecomment-1741899666) post. I have also tried turning the `autodetect` off.